# Send header in subsequent URL visits through cypress

Tags: cypress

I am using Cypress for website integration testing and I am overwriting visit method such that it includes specific attribute in header but [this](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit.html#Arguments) doc says that `headers will only be sent for the initial cy.visit() request, not for any subsequent requests`.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is asked long time ago but it might help others. I found a workaround to add headers for all requests:

```
cy.server({
       onAnyRequest:   function (route,  proxy) {
           proxy.xhr.setRequestHeader('CUSTOM-HEADER',  'Header value');
     }
});
```